# Java: image not loading in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I searched a lot on Stack Overflow and followed the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889608/accessing-image-paths-in-eclipse).
But I am still getting `IllegalArgumentException : input==null!` for the following lines:

```
BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/images/bg.jpg"));    
ImageIcon logo=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/images/tucan.png")));
```

I tried everything but still no success. My directory structure is this:
News -->res-->images-->bg.jpg,tucan.png

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add your `res` folder to the list of `source folders`.

Right Click -> Build Path -> Use as source folder

If you don't, then Eclipse won't copy the folder into the output folder and you can't access them in the way you tried to do.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.One additional question-is it(using `ImageIO.read`) the efficient way of loading images when I have say 15 such images.

Comment: It's the only built-in way to do so, so you don't have a real choice. But, I didn't have any problems with `ImageIO` image reading so far.

Comment: @Neet - it's not the only built-in way (e.g. Toolkit.getImage), but probably the easiest (and newest) to use [:-)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yep, but `Toolkit` uses under the hood the same readers/importers as `ImageIO`. You can verify this by looking at the sources. So, there shouldn't be any difference. It's just another way for doing the same stuff^^

Comment: @Neet exactly it's another way - so there is not only one way! And are you sure they use the same readers/importers? Toolkit is AWT and seems like it does not use any class from imageio package; ImageIO on the other side seems not to use any awt classes despite BufferedImage and RenderedImage. And there is at least two difference: Toolkit caches the images and returns a ToolkitImage while ImageIO returns a BufferedImage!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger ah, yep, sry. I didn't see the difference on first sight. Strange.